# PHP parse array post

Tags: php, arrays, post

A page is posting an array to me like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fields[email_address][value]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="fields[first_name][value]" value="jim" />
<input type="text" name="fields[zip_code][value]" value="45254" />...
```

An array.

I can loop through it like this easy enough

```
    foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $key => $field ) {

        echo $key." ".$field['value'] ;
        }
```

Result of above:

first_name jim 
email_address 1 
address_postal_code 45254

But what I really need to do is reference just the zip (45254) out of the array, maybe like:

```
echo $_POST['fields']['zip_code']; //or
echo $_POST['fields']['zip_code']['value'];
```

result:  45254

Is this possible?

Comment: not seeing an issue, why not `echo $_POST['fields']['zip_code']['value']` ?

Comment: or drop the `[value]` from your input names

Comment: that's the first thing I tried.  notice my sting value:   echo $key." ".$field['value']

Comment: again, I have no control over the post its from a wordpress plugin.  So they post this jsonish array and one of the arrays is named 'fields'

Comment: how do I get field->zip_code->value ??

Answer (score 2):

Update

```
<input type="text" name="fields[zip_code][value]" value="45254" />
```

to be

```
<input type="text" name="fields[zip_code]" value="45254" />
```

Edit: I wasn't aware you can't modify the html, that wasn't specified in the original question.

The only thing you can really do is do:

```
$_POST['fields']['zip_code'] = $_POST['fields']['zip_code']['value'];
```

However at that point, you might as well just assign `$_POST['fields']['zip_code']['value']` to a variable and use that.

If you can't update the html of the form, all you can do is manipulate the data after it's been assigned to the $_POST superglobal like it's any other array

Edit 2: Adding a complete snippet to try:

If you do, what do you get?:

```
<?php
foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $key => $field ) {
    echo $key." ".$field['value'] ."<br />";
}
echo $_POST['fields']['zip_code']['value'] . "<br />";
$_POST['fields']['zip_code'] = $_POST['fields']['zip_code']['value'];
echo $_POST['fields']['zip_code'];
?>
```

I just tried that with a simple form of:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
  <input type="text" name="fields[email_address][value]" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="fields[first_name][value]" value="jim" />
  <input type="text" name="fields[zip_code][value]" value="45254" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And it works as expected.

Comment: please quote array keys

Comment: no, it shouldn't have quotes.  This is an html input name, adding quotes will add quotes to the keys in the POST data, but i'll update to include the full html tag

Comment: I am not making the post and have no control over it.  Its coming from a wordpress plugin

Comment: foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $key => $field ) {

        echo $key." ".$field['value']."<br>" ;
        }

Comment: returns:   first_name jim
email_address 1
address_postal_code 45254
        }

Comment: I just tried it again echo $_POST['fields']['zip_code']['value']; returns nothing

Comment: I'm guessing something is happening and the post data isn't making it to your script then.  Try the snippet I just edited my answer with.  Everything is working as expected for me

Answer (score 0):

This seems sloppy but it worked:

```
foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $key => $field ) {

$$key = $field['value'] ;
        }

echo $address_postal_code;
```

45254

```
echo $_POST['fields']['zip_code']['value']
```

returns nothing